# Sweat and touch screen issues

Tags: phone

I am recently working on a project. I had to visit site day before yesterday. I will be staying there for next 6 days. The problem here is that the temperature is warm and due to working in sun body is generating sweat.

The sweat in pants and near the pocket area makes pocket wet. And this wet pocket drains excess sweat on my phone.  Whenever I try to unlock the wet phone touchscreen doesn't respond properly. I have to wipe it with cotton cloth to make it function properly.

My phone physical details:
Capacitive touchscreen with gorilla glass 3. I haven't  attached any screen guard or protector. I don't have flip cover and I am not interested in flip cover as I am in this location for 6 days only.

Is there any hack to prevent my phone screen from getting wet due to sweat.

One solution I have tried:
Wrapped my handkerchief on my phone it works OK. But I have to wrap handkerchief every time I put phone in pocket

Comment: Well, as you said, its only for six days, so wrapping it in something absorbent would appear to be the best solution, even if it is tedious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use plastic sandwich bags for everything (storing cables & cords so they don't get tangled, for example), and if you place your phone in a bag in your pocket it will not get any moisture on it. You don't need to seal the bag; that would just make it harder to take the phone out and wouldn't give much benefit.

I imagine the bag might even stick to the inside of your pocket a little bit, which would make it a pretty excellent "pocket-liner".  It might stay in your pocket when you take your phone out, and be easy to put your phone back into. No one would even notice you had it in there. (Maybe. I haven't tried it myself.)

Plastic bags are very inexpensive in the grocery stores in my area, and probably in yours too. If you're really lucky, the site that you're at might even have some in its lunchroom.  (My office does.)

Answer (score 3):

You could try a [self sealing waterproof bag](http://www.kitbag.com.au/products/Waterproof-Seal-Again-Bag-%252d-Large.html). These are often issued to soldiers to keep important papers/items clean and dry while on operations.

The link provided is for an Australian website, but you should be able to find these or similar at an army surplus/disposals type store.

Answer (score 1):

I was a late adopter of smartphones for a geek. I bought my first one while travelling in China and gave it a serious impairment within a few months while hitchhiking in Southeast Asia. From the sweat in my pocket.

In Southeast Asia it's rainy for about half the year and you're sweating for about the entire year.

The discount stores sell various kinds of locking plastic bag thingies for protecting your phone from rain, which also works for sweat.

But the poor people, of whom there are very many, just use whatever random clean plastic bag they were last given when they bought something.

One of the proper ones from a phone shop would be best if you want to be able to see and use your touchscreen through the plastic. But if it's just against sweat then any random plastic bag, and take it out of the bag when you want to use it. When you're going to be getting extra sweaty, on a long walk or a workout, then tie a couple of knots in the bag.